# "Temporary table" - Incorrect syntax near x

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I get the error Incorrect syntax near x. Why ? Also, is x a temporary table. If not, then what is it ?

```
select sum(x.count)
from
(
  select  count(id) as 'count'
  from    table1   
) x
```

The above query might work. But, when the same logic is applied to the query below, i get the same error - Incorrect syntax near table_name-

```
select sum(table_name.an_alias)
from 
(select 
  top 5
  avg(some_value) as an_alias
  where (some_condition)
  group by a_date
)table_name
```

When you run only the inner query, it produces a datetime column and a int column. 
I want to use the outer select to sum that int column.

Comment: Table is a key word, replace table with the name of a table?

Comment: try `select sum(x.[count])`

Comment: Have you oversimplified this? I can change to actual tables I have and the syntax runs just fine. What are you not telling us about this query?

Comment: Is table1 actually defined?

Comment: @HLGEM - okay. I will give you an overview of the REAL query(see edit in question). The real query looks like the one in my question. So, I foolishly assumed that problems in REAL query will be the same as question query. Sorry.

Comment: missing a from, is that a typo or the problem

Comment: @HLGEM - oops, sorry. Fixed that and now it says - no column was specified for column 1 of table_name. How do i fix this ?

Comment: Fix for the problem - http://www.sqlerror.sqlserver-training.com/msg-8155-level-16-state-2-line-2-no-column-was-specified-for-column-d-of-ls/- 
The solution to this error is You must specify (either explicitly or implicitly) a column name of each column of a derived table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query works from me, assuming you use the actual table name, and not "from table".

In your query, x is an alias for your subquery.  You might call it a table alias, but in this case it aliases a subquery and not a table.

Comment: So, how do i make it some kind of "temporary table" and then access the columns ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  You can access the columns of the subquery.  No need for a temp table.

Answer (score 1):

try with brackets instead of songle quotes

```
 select sum(x.count)
 from  ( select count(id) as [count]
         from table) x,
```

Change the alias 'count'  to 'cny' and see what happens...

```
 select sum(x.cnt)
 from  ( select count(id) cnt
         from table) x,
```

but realize that the subquery will have only one row since you are not grouping on anything, so this should be equivalent to just

```
select count(id) from table
```

Comment: changed table to table1, the brackets don't make a difference. I am still getting the same error. :(

Comment: Is there a table in the database named table1 ?  What happens if you just run the subquery ? `select count(id) from table1`  ?